# How to read data of multiple input model using tf.data.TextlineDataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

### Model

I've created a model with **multiple inputs** which can be embedding index or continuous numbers. For example, there are three inputs whose name are `input1`, `input2` and `input3` specifically, and they are `fixed length embedding index`, `variable length embedding index` and `continuous numbers`.

### Data

The format of data file is organized as follow:

```
input1 input2   input3   label
1       1,2    0.51,0.62   2
```

All inputs are separated by tab(\t).

`Variable length embedding index` and `continuous numbers` input values are separated by comma(,) .

### Load Data

Now I want to load the train data from data files. And I use `tf.data.TextLineDataset` for that purpose. But how can I convert the value of input2 and input3 to a array tensor for training and eval? I've tried map function of `Dataset`.

### Snipped code

```py
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset('file.tsv')
dataset = dataset.map(labeler)

def labeler(record):
    fields = tf.decode_csv(record, record_defaults=['0', '0', '0', 0], field_delim='\t')
    label = fields[-1]
    del fields[-1]

    data = dict()
    data['input1'] = tf.cast(fields[0], dtype=int64)
    # How to do with input2 and input3??
    data['input2'] = ??
    data['input3'] = ??

    return data, label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this question myself, Here the code of function `labeler`:

```py
def labeler(record):
    fields = tf.io.decode_csv(record,
                              record_defaults=['0'] * 4,
                              field_delim='\t',
                              select_cols=list(range(0, 4)))
    data = dict()
    data['input1'] = tf.strings.to_number(fields[0], out_type='int64')
    data['input2'] = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split([fields[1]],
                                                           sep=',').values,
                                          out_type='int64')
    data['input3'] = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split([fields[2]],
                                                           sep=',').values,
                                          out_type='float64')
    label = tf.strings.to_number(fields[-1], out_type='int64')

    return data, label
```

**Notice:**

If you want to batch the dataset above using `batch` fuction, it will fail. Because the dataset has the variable length input field.

The method to solve this problem is to use `padded_batch` function of dataset. And as you have multiple input, you should set the `shape` for each input using tuple which will be passed to `padded_batch`. Here is the code:

```py
shapes = ({'input1': [], 'input2': [None], 'input3': []}, [])
dataset = dataset.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat(2).padded_batch(batch_size,
                                                       padded_shapes=shapes)
```

`[]` means no pad, `[None]` means pad to the longest record in that batch using `0`.

Although this works, whether padded with all `0` affect the `training effect` is still unknown. If you have any idea, it's very pleasure to hear your voice.